# Adding Same type of collection as children in different parent entity within the same DataContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

category collection will be children of either Transaction Entity or Product Entity. 
And Product Collection Always children of category. But when adding category collection to product, it also shows the categories added in transaction.
Here is the code.

```
    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var data = new ProductContext())
        {
            var t = new Transaction();
            data.Transaction.Add(t);
            t.Dscr = "t1";

            var c = new Category{  Name= "cat under trans 1"};
            t.Categories.Add(c);
            var p = new Product{ Name="p 1"};

            var c1 = new Category{  Name= "cat under product 1"};
            p.Categories.Add(c1);

            //******p.Categories ALSO SHOWS t.Categories **************//

            c.Products.Add(p);

            data.SaveChanges(); 
        }
    }

public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext()
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "workstation id=.;packet size=4096;user id=sa ;Password =123;data source=.; Initial Catalog=YRX;persist security info=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; connection timeout=5"; //ConnectionString                            // ConnectionString;
        //this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public Transaction()
    {
        this.Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int TransId { get; set; }
    public string Dscr { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("TransId")] 
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; private set; }

}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")] 
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? TransId { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")] 
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how can I add categories under transaction and under product, from above code when I add categories under transaction it also shows in categories under product